# phpBB, how to make a new install point at an old database?

Tags: database, migration, phpbb

I'm building a completely new version of my website (currently runs on phpBB and a custom CMS). I'm using Wordpress and phpBB this time. When I'm done and ready to make the switch, I'm having trouble deciding how to actually do it.

I'd love to just leave the phpBB database exactly where it is and then somehow make my new phpBB forums just consider that phpBB database its database instead of having to do some sort of export/import.

Can I just copy the config file of the old forum and paste it into the new forum? I want this to be seamless and I want the only thing my users know about/see is just that there is magically this new skin on their site. I don't want them to have to re-register or anything like that.

Is this possible?

Comment: are you upgrading the version of phpBB on your new install, or just adding a new skin?

Comment: Haven't gotten that far yet. Let's just assume I'm just adding a new skin. I'll burn the upgrading bridge when I'm trying to cross it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the version of your new phpbb location is the same and you remain on the same server and domain, all you would have to do is to copy the config.php file of the old forum into the new forum location, overwriting the default. If your path to the forum is different in the new forum instance, you will then have to manually go into phpbb_config table and change the script_path configuration key value. Please note however that any modifications you had previously made to the source code of the old forum would not show in the new location if you are using standard phpbb zip file, so you will have to manually apply all of those.

Pete